# Updating a model in the database (update or overwrite)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

When updating a model in the database, is it better to just update the particular field, or overwrite other objects of the same level with the field?

Comment: Just update the field, why not?

Comment: Yes. That is what I thought too. But I have seen some services that will simply overwrite the whole object and wonder if there are any justification for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MongoDB docs :

> The update() method either modifies specific fields in existing documents or replaces an existing document entirely.
>   Update Specific Fields
>   If the `<update>` document contains update operator modifiers, such as
>   those using the $set modifier, then:
>
> The `<update>` document must contain only update operator expressions.
>   The `update()` method updates only the corresponding fields in the
>   document. To update an embedded document or an array as a whole,
>   specify the replacement value for the field. To update particular
>   fields in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation to
>   specify the field.
>
> Replace a Document Entirely If the `<update>` document contains only
>   field:value expressions, then:
>
> The update() method replaces the matching document with the `<update>`
>   document. The update() method does not replace the _id value. For an
>   example, see Replace All Fields. update() cannot update multiple
>   documents.

My personal opinion is to overwrite the depending objects as well, so that proper versioning is maintained. If there is no update id or if the id does not change, then updating should do the job. But if you want to maintain the versioning it is better to overwrite the whole object.